# Green giant Arborvitae natural fence

Tags: trees, mulch, fence

I want to create a 100 ft natural fence using Green Giants in the back row (30-50 ft ht) and staggering western green giant (15-30 ft ht)in the front. Is it best to mulch around each plant and mow the grass between them while they are young, or just remove the entire length of grass and make a long mulch bed with a tarp between the trees? I’m worried that using my zero turn mover around the young 4 ft trees might hurt them. I want the least maintenance possible. Is it best to use wood chips for mulch around the trees?

Answer (score 1):

Skip the tarp, invert the sod, and use ENOUGH wood chips (or whatever other mulch is handy - straw also works, but where I am it costs a lot more) to make an effective mulch. 4-6" will work. 2" generally won't keep weeds down.

You'll still need to yank the occasional weed that gets started, but it should not be a major battle if you don't let them go to seed.

Comment: No need to invert the sod if the OP uses 8" or more of woodchips for the first year; they won't need to add more chips for at least two years after that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you think a long row of mulch will be easier to maintain compared to mulch just around the trees?